# Como puedo hacer que se impriman variables aleatorias en consola? C#

Tags: c#

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion, y lo que quiero hacer realmente es poder imprimir en consola variables distintas pero de forma aleatoria cada vez que se ejecture, me explico

Quiero poder tener las variables: Casa,Auto y Avion y que al compilar, en consola se me muestre solamente 1 de esas 3 pero de forma aleatoria, como se puede hacer esto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Metelas dentro de una lista, y selecciona alguna posicion de la lista al azar...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pues genera un número aleatorio y decide que variable quieres que se imprima en base a él.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lleva las palabras esas a un arreglo

var transportes = string[] { "Casa", "Auto", "Avion"}

Casa esta en la posicion 0
Auto esta en la posicion 1
Avion esta en la posicion 2

Luego con la Clase Random puedes generar numeros aleatorios

```
Random rnd = new Random();

var aleatorio = rnd.Next(0, 3)
```

luego solo muestra la posicion del arreglo

```
Console.WriteLine(transportes[aleatorio]);
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mejorando la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/548086/3484) de McCover agregando el código completo:

```
// Crear un array con tus valores, son 3 en total
var transportes = new string[] { "Casa", "Auto", "Avion" };

// Crear una instancia de Random para generar un valor aleatorio
var rnd = new Random();

// Se calcula un valor aleatorio entre 0 y la longitud de tu array. 
// Se utiliza el -1 para que obtenga hasta la posición 2 que es el 
// último elemento del array
var aleatorio = rnd.Next(0, transportes.Length - 1);

Console.WriteLine(transportes[aleatorio]);
```

Comment: Si querias mejorar una respuesta, tendrias que explicar en que la mejora...